# Any-type variable assignment

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to get warn from compiler in way like this:

```
let a: any = '123';
let b: number;
let c: string = '123';

b = a; <--- I want warning
b = c; <--- compile error
```

or may be something like tslint can do that?

Comment: This is like asking how to make your alarm clock ring while it's in the "off" setting. Why is it off in the first place?

Comment: I made mistake by use "error"-word on the first place... I mean warn.
Or what do you mean?

Comment: The answer says it all: the `any` type is assignable and can be assigned to any other variable by design. If you don't want that, don't use `any`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to get warn from compiler in way like this

No. `any` is a type explicitly existing for the purpose of compatibility with all (i.e. any) types.